# Pretty-Print a JsonElement of kotlinx

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx

I have a kotlinx JsonElement at hand, and I want to pretty-print it.

How do I do that? The only methods I see for pretty-print need a data class, but my element does not fit any specific class.

//EDIT: added some code example

```
fun print(json: JsonObject) : String {
    val withVersion = jsonObject + ("Version" to 1.1)
    return withVersion.toString()  // returns wrong json
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, post code sample and what have you tried. But kotlinx `Json` does have a [`prettyPrint` configuration](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx.serialization.json/-json-builder/) option, is that not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I feel quite stupid.
encodeToString works correctly even if the object is JsonElement.

Simply

```
Json { prettyPrint = true }.encodeToString(withVersion)
```